# What is the solution for same value unifying?

Tags: c#, linq

Writing Othello with a twist: Only storing the black, white and the legal moves in Piece type lists.

```
public class Piece
    {
        //coordinates of the pieces on the board
        //X=0 Y=0 is the SouthWest corner of the board
        public int X, Y;
        //references to other pieces, 0 is SouthWest, 1 is West, ... 7 is South
        public Piece[] neighbours = new Piece[8];
        


        public Piece(int xLocation, int yLocation) {
            this.X = xLocation;
            this.Y = yLocation;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                this.neighbours[i] = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is a missing snippet from:

```
        {
            List<Piece> legalMoves = new List<Piece>();
            Piece element;

            for (int i = 0; i < enemy.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    int xOffset = 0;
                    int yOffset = 0;
                    if (j % 4 != 3)
                    {
                        if (j < 3)
                        {
                            xOffset = -1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            xOffset = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (j % 4 != 1)
                    {
                        if (j > 1 && j < 5)
                        {
                            yOffset = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            yOffset = -1;
                        }
                    }
                    int newX = enemy[i].X + xOffset;
                    int newY = enemy[i].Y + yOffset;
                    if (enemy[i].neighbours[j] == null && newX >= 0 && newX <= 7 && newY >= 0 && newY <= 7)
                    {
                        int direction = (j + 4) % 8;
                        element = enemy[i].neighbours[direction];
                        while (element != null && !enemy.Contains(element))
                        {
                            element = enemy[i].neighbours[direction];
                        }
                        if (element != null)
                        {
                            legalMoves.Add(new Piece(newX, newY));
                            legalMoves[legalMoves.Count - 1].neighbours[direction] = enemy[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //missing snippet here
          
            return legalMoves;
        }
```

The missing snippet needs to transform the LegalMoves before return like this:

LegalMoves example without snippet:

```
X | Y | neighbours[0] | neighbours[1] | neighbours[2] | neighbours[3] |...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0 | 0 |     null      |      null     |   PieceRef    |     null      |...
0 | 1 |     null      |      null     |   PieceRef    |     null      |...
0 | 1 |     null      |    PieceRef   |     null      |     null      |...
1 | 0 |     null      |      null     |     null      |   PieceRef    |...
0 | 1 |   PieceRef    |      null     |     null      |     null      |...
1 | 0 |   PieceRef    |      null     |     null      |     null      |...
```

LegalMoves example with snippet:

```
X | Y | neighbours[0] | neighbours[1] | neighbours[2] | neighbours[3] |...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0 | 0 |     null      |      null     |    PieceRef   |     null      |...
0 | 1 |   PieceRef    |    PieceRef   |    PieceRef   |     null      |...
1 | 0 |   PieceRef    |      null     |      null     |   PieceRef    |...
```

More precisely:
The LegalMoveList without the snippet is creating a list, where multiple elements have the same X and Y value, but with different neigbours array.
The code above the missing snippet adds only those elements, which fullfill certain criterias:

-In the neighbours array only one element is Piece referency, the other seven is null.

-Where the X and Y is the same in multiple elements the location of the Piece reference is not the same. e.g.: If element1 and element2 have the same X and Y value, and element1.neighbours[0] is a Piece reference, then element2.neighbours[0] is null.

The task for the missing snippet would be to unify those elements.
Every X and Y pair needs to be unique. If it was not unique before the snippet, then one element must "inherit" the not-null values of the neighbours array (This way those criterias come in handy, do not need to concern about the "collision").

LINQ solutions is much appreciated, but if not possible, then a plain code is good as well.

Please write if the explanation is not proper.

Comment: Why did you delete and repost this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67097482/what-is-the-solution-to-same-key-unifying

Comment: Dear @Enigmativity ! My previous question was closed because of "Needs details or clarity". My solution to that was to delete and post it with more information. In that time that was the best i could think of. Please excuse my beginner mistake on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a sequence of `Pieces`, called `LegalMoves`, where some `Pieces` might have the same location (= values for x and y).

You want to combine the Pieces with the same location into one Piece according to the following rule

> Every X and Y pair needs to be unique. If it was not unique before the snippet, then one element must "inherit" the not-null values of the neighbours array (This way those criterias come in handy, do not need to concern about the "collision").

In other words: from a group of Pieces, that all have the same location, you want to make one Piece. For every index 0..7, you want the zero or one non-null Neighbour with this index.

So if you have 25 Pieces in a group, then at utmost one of them will have a non-null value for Neighbours[4], and at utmost one of them will have a non-null value for Neighbours[0], etc.

Whenever you want to make groups of items that have something in common, consider to use one of the overloads of [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby). If you want to make one element from each Group, use an overload that has a parameter `resultSelector`

So you want to make groups of Pieces that have the same location:

```
var result = legalMoves.GroupBy(legalMove => new
{
    X = legalMove.X,
    Y = legalMove.Y,
},

// TODO parameter resultSelector
```

In words: we have an object, called legalMoves, which is a sequence of Pieces. from every legalMove in the sequence of legalMoves, make one `key`. This key is an object with two properties: the X and the Y of the legalMove. Make groups of Pieces that have the same value for this key.

Parameter `resultSelector` is a function that has two input parameters: the `key`, we just created and all legalMoves that have this value for `key`. Every legalMove is a Piece. The  return value of the function is one Piece.

Something like this:

```
Piece CreateResult(TKey key, IEnumerable<Piece> legalMovesWithThisKey) {...}
```

As a Lambda we write it as:

```
(key, legalMovesWithThisKey => new Piece {...}
```

So what do we want with this new Piece:

- Location is the Location of all elements in the group: so the X and Y of the Key
- Neighbours is an array of 8 Pieces, where every Piece is the first element in the Neighbours group that has a non-null value for the Piece index.

The last sentence is a difficult way to say that Neighbours[0] is the one and only Neighbours[0] value that is not null, or null if all values are null. Similar for Neighbours[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby), [2] etc.

```
(key, legalMovesWithThisKey => new Piece
{
    X = key.X,
    Y = key.Y,

    Neighbours = Enumerable.Range(0, 8)
       .Select(index => legalMovesWithThisKey
                        .select(legalMove => legalMove.Neighbours[index])
                        .Where(neighbour => neighbour != null)
                        .FirstOrDefault())
       .ToArray();
}
```

For Neighbours: enumerate the 8 indexes from 0..7, and for every index, use all legalMovesWithThisKey to get the neighbour with this index. Get the first one that is not null, or null if there is no first one.

So for index 3, Get the Neighbours[3] for every legalMove in this group, and take the first one that has a non-null value. Because you guaranteed that there wouldn't be more than one, the order is not important.

By the way: Your Piece has no method to access the neighbours. I took the liberty to add public get / set properties for X Y Neighbours. To make efficient use of LINQ methods, it is wise to create objects with default constructor and to have proper get / set

Answer (score 0):

Try using a datatable :

```
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           dt.Columns.Add("X", typeof(int));
           dt.Columns.Add("Y", typeof(int));
           dt.Columns.Add("neighbours0", typeof(string));
           dt.Columns.Add("neighbours1", typeof(string));
           dt.Columns.Add("neighbours2", typeof(string));
           dt.Columns.Add("neighbours3", typeof(string));

           dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {0,0, "","","PieceReg", ""});
           dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {0,1, "","","PieceReg", ""});
           dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {0,1, "","PieceReg", "", ""});
           dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,0, "","","", "PieceReg"});
           dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {0,1, "PieceReg","","", ""});
           dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,0, "PieceReg","","", ""});
```